# How to paint in canvas holding the mouse and not clicking

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So here's the code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


canvas.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(evt.x, evt.y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
}, false); 

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

The problem i'm having is when i try to paint, it paints on the canvas when i'm clicking, but what i want is that it paints when **i'm holding my finger on the canvas.**

Edit: what i want is to make a paint tool, i want that when i'm dragging to draw in the canvas it draws. But in my code it draws when i'm clicking. I'm using a touchscreen so it needs to work for mobile and pc.

**When i'm holding in the canvas and then drag it dosn't continue drawing**

This is how i want it to be: http://literallycanvas.com/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent is what you want to read about.

Answer (score 0):

```
// object to store mouse position reading
var mousePosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

function onMouseMove(event) {
   // detect possible changes in mouse position
   if (mousePosition.x != event.clientX  || mousePosition.y != event.clientY ) {
      mousePosition.x = event.clientX;
      mousePosition.y = event.clientY;
    // code to draw goes here ....
  }
}

// use mouse move event on the canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
```

additionally, one could set an interval inside the onMouseMove if clause to space out drawing steps.

Comment: Not working. Now when i'm holding the mouse in the canvas, i need to stop holding the mouse to draw. What i want is that it draws at when i'm holding it not when i hold and stop.

Comment: @ Hello man, maybe edit your question to explain exactly what you mean. I assumed (in my snippet below, which works perfectly well if you you run it here by clicking the button and click-drag your mouse in the box that appears) that you want to draw when clicking and holding the mouse down. If not, explain what you want.

Comment: Ok i'll explain better

Answer (score 0):

Click events trigger once per click and any data you extract from the event pertains to that instant. As the first answer states, mousemove is the event you want to look into.

I've made a working implementation below that I think does what you are after, it uses three event listeners `mousedown` sets a boolean to enable drawing, `mousemove` triggers drawing and updates continously, `mouseup` toggles the boolean set by `mousedown` to prevent drawing unless you're golding the mouse down while moving the mouse.

I reduced the radius of your circle as I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to draw, it now traces the mouse.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let mouseDown = false;
let mouseUp = true;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  mouseDown = !mouseDown; // toggle mouseDown true/false;      
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
  redraw(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  mouseDown = !mouseDown; // toggle mouseDown true/false;
});


function redraw(X,Y) {

  // console.log(X, Y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(X, Y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: I tested on the snippet it dosn't work at all

Comment: @Hello man What doesn't work about it?  try clicking the 'run code snippet' button, then click and drag your cursor in the canvas box that appears. if it doesn't work, best contact stackoverflow incase (unlikley) their snipped render is broken.

Comment: I'm testing this on a mobile and i'm sure the render isn't broken. I try holding and dragging on the canvas and nothing renders. ):

Comment: touch screen use different event listeners. Respectfully, you should have stated this in the question. Look it up yourself and don't waste peoples time here.

Comment: @Hello man Just noticed it wasn't your question, apologies for confusion. touch screen don't use a mouse, look up 'touchstart' and 'touchend'/'touchcancel'

Comment: Oh ok i thought mouse was also for mobile sorry for mistake

Comment: The logic in the answers looks sound, you may just need to get your head around the mobile device event differences and substitute them.

Answer (score 0):

Side remark: `mousePos` is not used in the original code, that's why it probably draws into a shifted position. [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) has `offsetX` and `offsetY`, you could use them directly instead of any extra calculations.

If you just want to draw whenever the user moves the mouse over the canvas, regardless of pushing or not pushing a button, `mousemove` is the event you could use:

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
  let canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(evt) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
</script>
```

If you want something to happen even when the mouse is not moving, just it's over the canvas, some kind of timer is needed. Here it's just a simple [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is enough for a simple test:

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
  let canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  let lastevent = false;
  let r = 0;

  function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (lastevent) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + ",0,0)";
      r += 8;
      if (r > 255) r = 0;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(lastevent.offsetX, lastevent.offsetY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    lastevent = evt;
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    lastevent = evt;
    animate();
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    lastevent = false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's drawing only when i click, i want it to draw also when i draw and hold.

Comment: @Helloman the snippet your comment relates to (the first one of the two) has absolutely nothing to do with clicks. Are you really using a mouse, or is it a touchscreen?

Comment: It works on my touchscreen but it draws when i click not when i hold my finger in the canvas

Comment: When i hold and drag it dosn't continue drawing

Comment: @Helloman I don't have a touchscreen at hand, but tried adding a `touchmove` handler to the first snippet. It may or may not work.